# How to reset all components in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to restart my component when the route changes:

```
  beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {
    Object.assign(this.$data, this.$options.data())
      console.log(to.query);
      next();
    }
```

but it doesn't work; it only prints the console.log. I've also tried `this.$options.data.call(this)` and `apply`.

Comment: Have a look at this post, this solution should work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35604987/is-there-a-proper-way-of-resetting-a-components-initial-data-in-vuejs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to force Vue to re-render same component upon route query change, it is possible to assign a `key` to the `<router-view` it mount's into and push router to the page with the same route name or path.

Example:

Mounting point:

```
<router-view
  :key="$route.fullPath"
/>
```

Component navigation, assuming route name is `blog`

```
<router-link :to={ name: 'blog', query: { count: 10 } }>Link to the same route</router-link>
```

This is assuming that you want to reset data of page component while navigating to the same page component with different data.

If component that you want to reset is not the route component, it is possible to reset it's data with `watch` option, while saving original data.

Example:

```
data () {
  return {
    initialData: {
      //  some initial data
    },
    data: {}
  }
},
watch: {
  '$route.fullPath': {
    immediate: true, // Immediate option to call watch handler on first mount
    handler () {
      this.resetData()
    }
  }
},
methods: {
  resetData () {
    this.data = Object.assign({}, this.initialData)
  },
},
```

Note, that any `$route` options can be watched and additional conditions added to handler via next and previous arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Try 
          this.$router.reload()

Comment: i'm don't need to reload router but reload only current component